# Go packaging: How to avoid 'cannot find package' error when submitting PRs from fork?

Tags: git, go

I am running into what sounds like a limitation in an overall simple approach for integrating git with go install.

1. I've forked a git repo on github
2. I now have to deal with changing packages in the same repo to reference correctly my own fork.
3. Then when I am ready to submit a PR, I need to revert the package imports while I won't be able to compile and install the changes.
4. I could keep 2 repos and cherry pick the lines I need to change but that seems too complicated by 2016.

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have forked `github.com/user1/goproject` into `github.com/user2/goproject`, that does not mean you cannot clone it wherever you want in your `GOPATH`.

In particular, you can clone it in:

```
$GOPATH
  github.com
    user1
      goproject
```

You effectively are replacing the local clone of the original repo by the clone of your fork.

That means locally, you don't change any package path, even though `git remote -v` tells you are are pushing back to your fork url `github.com/user2/goproject`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that I could just rename the directory to 'user1' locally while remote repo url is different, for things to work correctly.